# magento routing not works when i enabled 'Add Store Code to Urls' in admin

Tags: magento-1.9, url, 404-page, routing, store-id

when i change   **Add Store Code to Urls**  to  **yes** at

**system > web > url options** in admin panel,

all the routing to my controller is not works. returns 404 error page. how to resolve this?

Comment: just to check that you reindexed and now you are visiting  url www.site/storecode/module/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

append your store code like this

http://example.com/storeCode/frontName/controllerName/actionName/

here the storeCode is what you set in the admin panel under **system > manage stores**